# How to implement Sequence in Azure Synapse

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-synapse

I want to provide incremental value (+1) to one of the column in my Synapse table.

I tried to create a Sequence (to get next value from it), but seems it is not supported in Synapse for now.
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-azure-synapse-analytics/suggestions/19746709-support-sequence-types-in-sql-dw

I also tried to define that particular column as IDENTITY (1,1). Sample:

```
create table test.seq(
seq1 int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
name varchar(10)
);
```

But it is not working as expected because when I execute my insert query, the values got skip for the column i.e. I am not getting continuous value (1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10...). Seems it is because of MPP execution in Synapse.

Can someone please help, how can I implement sequence in Synapse table or any other workaround where I can get continuous values (with +1).

Comment: Neither `IDENTITY` or a `SEQUENCE` guarantees the values to be continuous in the table. If a row is deleted, a `INSERT` fails, a transaction is rolled back, etc etc, then gaps will form. That is documented and expected. You should *not* rely on an `IDENTITY` to be continuous; it will **not** be.

Comment: As you can see in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f2514f0b5a980e5abf79a5a4f952884f) just a couple of failed insert, and a `DELETE` introduce gaps all over the place.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. Do we have some workaround or equivalent functionality for it in Synapse? Just like we have Sequence and Nextval in Oracle DB.

Comment: The behaviour isn't unique to Synapse, it happens across the board. If you need a continuous number, you are better off using `ROW_NUMBER`.